# c++ Converting a std::string to int, double, etc WITHOUT using a char array

Tags: c++, string

In C++ I have only seen this done by converting the string object into an array of characters. The tutorials with an array are a bit hard for me to understand. But I want to do the conversion without the array.

I do have an idea how to do it: the string is "1234". After that I convert this text to an integer this way:

```
if (symol4 == "4") int_var += 4 * 1;
if (symol3 == "3") int_var += 3 * 10;
if (symol3 == "2") int_var += 2 * 100;
if (symol3 == "1") int_var += 1 * 1000; //Don't worry, I'm familiar with cycles, this code is only for explaining my algorithm
```

I hope you can understand the idea.

But I don't know if this is the best way. I don't know if there is a library that has a function that allows me to do that (I won't be surprised if there is one).

I don't know if not using a char array is a good idea. But that's a different question that I'm going to ask later.

What's the best way to convert a string to an integer, double, etc WITHOUT using an array of characters.

Comment: But string **is** by definition an array of characters!

Comment: are you referring to std::string ? Because otherwise string is indeed an array of characters.

Comment: littleadv, I know. But I want to do that without another array of characters.

Comment: It seems that you want to treat each digit as a (sub)string? A digit is just one *character*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`boost::lexical_cast` to the rescue: `int result = boost::lexical_cast<int>(input)`

If you don't want to rely on boost, you can use a stringstream, something like:

```
std::stringstream ss;
int result;
ss << input;
ss >> result;
```

but that's rather roundabout imo

And no don't use `atoi` - that function was flawed even back in C and it hasn't gotten better with time. It returns 0 when an error happened while parsing - which has the obvious problem how you distinguish an error from parsing the string `"0"`.

Comment: I like "And no don't use atoi"!

Comment: I think the question is saying he wants to take `1234` and break that up into 4 ints, `4`, `30`, `200` and `1000`.

Comment: boost::lexical_cast it is. Thanks!

Comment: `int result = ((std::stringstream()<<input) >> output).str();`

Answer (score 5):

I really can't get what your pasted code is about, but in C++ the best way to convert string to integer or float is to use `stringstream`.

```
const char* str = "10 20.5";
std::stringstream ss(str);
int x;
float y;

ss >> x >> y;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a function [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) which you can use. This converts it to a character array, but you don't have to do the math involved with indexing the array in a for loop.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...
String number = "1234";    
int value = atoi(number.c_str());
std::cout << number;
...
```

For the atoi nay sayers, hopefully he'll understand this >.>

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

try {
    int x = boost::lexical_cast<int>( "123" );
} catch( boost::bad_lexical_cast const& ) {
    std::cout << "Error: input string was not valid" << std::endl;
}
```

The best way is the most efficient way, I don't think you'll find a better alternative to this, or using a character array.

Comment: `atoi` in a question tagged for c++? I hope not. The design problems with THAT function are numerous.

Answer (score 1):

The standard string class already has a member function that gives you access to the internal character array, c_str(), so you can just pass this to one of the standard C library functions that parse integers, such as strtol():

```
string s = "1234";
long n = strtol(s.c_str(), 0, 10);
```

That's the simplest code if you already know the string is a valid integer and don't care about error checking. If you want full error checking you would do something like this:

```
char* end = 0;
errno = 0;
long n = strtol(s.c_str(), &end, 10);
if (end == 0 || *end == 0)
    throw invalid_argument("Not a number");
else if (errno == ERANGE)
    throw overflow_error("Number is out of range");
else if (errno != 0)
    throw invalid_argument("Not a number");
```

Alternatively you could use C++ streams if you want to avoid C style character arrays completely (or rather, hide them completely inside the classes):

```
istringstream in(s);
int n;
in >> n;
```

You could also use boost::lexical_cast, which does basically the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

- I recommend Boost.Lexical_Cast
- Or see the upcoming Boost.Conversion
- Can also be achieved using Boost.Spirit, but is somewhat more complex

See "The String Formatters of Manor Farm" [article](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill19.htm) by Herb Sutter.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look at the [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) function.

Comment: This question has C++ tag, not C.